# F# - Weight (Unit of Measure) Stones-Pounds

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I have a csv file containing daily weights as follows:

```
Date,Name,Weight
11-Sep-2017,Alpha,9-1
13-Sep-2017,Alpha,8-13
15-Sep-2017,Alpha,8-11
```

Though I can successfully import them using CsvProvider, the weight column defaults to System.DateTime.

```
    // Weight
    [<Measure>] type lb

    [<Literal>]
    let input = "DayWeights.csv"
    type Weights = CsvProvider<input, HasHeaders=true>

    let data = Weights.GetSample()
    for row in data.Rows do
        printfn "Output: (%A, %A, %A)" row.Date row.Name row.Weight
```

Is it possible to create a Unit of Measure (UoM) to define "stlb" with the option to convert to lbs on import and, if so, how?

Comment: You don't specify any type, so the type provider has to infer the type. Why should use the *unknown* `lb` measure? Why would a human by the way? `-` isn't used as a separator in any kind of numeric value

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the format of the csv file.

Comment: It's not the file. There's no way the provider can guess that you want to use `lb` by looking at the data. You have to tell it which type to use

Comment: It would help if I could import the weight field as a string and not suffer the automatic System.DateTime conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you could represent stones-pounds as a single numeric type, and units of measure can only be used on numeric types (although there is [some discussion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/563) about changing this in future). This is because some of their features only make sense with numeric operations like addition and multiplication. The units themselves are multiplied and divided:

```
[<Measure>] type lb
2<lb> + 2<lb> // 4<lb>
2<lb> * 2<lb> // 4<lb ^ 2>
2<lb> / 2<lb> // 1
```

Instead of units of measure, if you want some kind of tag to know that a given value has a type of stones-pounds, you could create a single case discriminated union:

```
type StonesPounds = StonesPounds of int * int

// StonesPounds -> int<lb>
let convertToLb (StonesPounds (s, p)) = (s * 14 + p) * 1<lb>

StonesPounds (1, 2) |> convertToLb // 16<lb>
```

The downside of this compared to units of measure is that you have to manually pack and unpack these values in code before you can use the numbers and there is a runtime cost for that too.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and guidance. How do I prevent the automatic conversion to System.DateTime of the input csv column?

Comment: Look at the "Controlling the column types" section of [this page](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html). You may need to make your own small example file with type hints that you pass to the type provider on creation, and then you can load the real file to work with the real data.

Comment: I'd suggest posting what you have tried as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the automatic converting of the input weight column to System.DateTime as follows:

```
// http://fssnip.net/27
let lazySplit (sep:string) (str:string) =
    match sep, str with
    | ((null | ""), _) | (_, (null | "")) -> seq [str]
    | _ ->
      let n, j = str.Length, sep.Length
      let rec loop p =
        seq {
          if p < n then
            let i = match str.IndexOf(sep, p) with -1 -> n | i -> i
            yield str.Substring(p, i - p)
            yield! loop (i + j)
        }
      loop 0

let weight input =
    input
    |> (fun x -> lazySplit "/" x |> Seq.take 2 |> String.concat("-"))

let data = Weighings.GetSample()
for row in data.Rows do
    let stlbs = weight (string row.Weight)
    printfn "Output: (%A, %A, %A)" row.Date row.Name stlbs

// Output: 11-Sep-2017,"Alpha","09-01")
```

Thanks to one and all for your expert help and guidance.